# What effect, if any, does talking to your players have?

Tags: lets-make-a-soccer-team

In the 2006 PS2 game *[Let's Make a Soccer Team](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let%27s_Make_a_Soccer_Team!)!*, one of the menu options is labelled "Talk To". Every in-game day, you can talk to four or five of your players, triggering a short cutscene in which they tell you one of several preset lines (the main one I remember being "This formation... I don't really get it.")

I've been playing the game on-and-off for years now, and I choose this option more or less every chance I get, but it's recently occurred to me that I don't know what it actually *does*. Does talking to your players have any in-game effect, or is it just there as fluff?